# Android Post запрос с параметром json

Tags: android

```
URL: http://www.l-tk.ru/mobile-api-v1/query/
data= {"type":1,"body":{"sortType":0,"categoryId":0,"count":50,"authorId":0,"lastId":0}}

@Override
protected T doInBackground(Object... params) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(API_URL + method.URL);


        String out = new Gson().toJson(request);

        Log.w("Log",out);

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + out.getBytes().length);

        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(out);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        connection.connect();

        String result = Utils.streamToString(connection.getInputStream());


        Log.w("Log_result", result);


        return (T) new Gson().fromJson(result, method.resultClass);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

out меня в итоге равен     {"body":{"authorId":0,"categoryId":0,"count":50,"lastId":0,"sortType":0},"type":1}

Не понимаю, куда засунуть "data="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не понял полного вопроса, возможно Вам нужно отправить этот JSON String в параметр data.
Могу дать рабочий код, в андроиде.

```
/**
 * Http POST request.
 *
 * @param url link to load from
 * @return error number, if success result will be in {@link
    #responseString}
 */
private int httpPost(String url, String data) {

Logger.d(logTag, "httpPost : url=" + url + " data=" + data);

int errorCode = Errors.ERR_SUCCESS;
responseString = null;
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

// Prepate parameters
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", data));

//Encoding POST data
try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));

    // make Http client and responder
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

    // Take status Line
    StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
    if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
        out.close();
        responseString = out.toString();
    } else {
        errorCode = Errors.ERR_HTTP_STATUS;
        //Closes the connection.
        response.getEntity().getContent().close();
        throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
    }
    // write response to log
    // Logger.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    errorCode = Errors.ERR_CLIENT_PROTOCOL_EXCEPTION;
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    errorCode = Errors.ERR_IOEXCEPTION;
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    errorCode = Errors.ERR_EXCEPTION;
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Logger.d(logTag, "httpPost : errorCode=" + errorCode);

return errorCode;
}
```